# Intous Draw pressure sensitivity not working

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, drawing-tablet, windows, wacom

I just bought my new Wacom Intuos Draw and it's working really well, but in Photoshop 2015.5 and Illustrator 2015.3.1 the pressure sensitivity is not working. When I go to Wacom tablet properties I can see that the pressure sensitivity is working well so is the Intuos incompatible with Adobe programs or should I change something in the settings to make the pressure sensitivity work?

OS: Windows 10 64bit

Comment: What kind of brush are you using? The brush needs to be set up to accept pressure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Illustrator** you can go to brushes and chose "**Touch Calligraphic Brush**" But if you want to make your own pressure sensitive Brush press new Calligraphic brush Change the size from fixed to "**pressure**" and pull "**size variation**" till the very end then change whatever you want in the brush options but **REMEMBER** if change the size later you should also change the variation.

For **Photoshop** open **Wacom tablet properties** at the top you can see bar called "Application" you will find Photoshop in the bar **(if you couldn't find it open Photoshop Then restart Wacom tablet properties)** Press it then press "**Mapping**" And be sure that "**Use Windows Ink**" is Checked. Now go back to Photoshop chose your brush tool then at the end of the second bar you will see icon that has a pen and circles press it and here you go